# Hidden features of mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There seem to be a decent number of `mod_rewrite` threads floating around lately with a bit of confusion over how certain aspects of it work. As a result I've compiled a few notes on common functionality, and perhaps a few annoying nuances.

What other features / common issues have you run across using `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask

Comment: See also `mod_rewrite tutorial for beginners` https://helponnet.com/2021/04/15/htaccess-tutorial-for-beginers/

Answer (score 203):

### Where to place mod_rewrite rules

`mod_rewrite` rules may be placed within the `httpd.conf` file, or within the `.htaccess` file. if you have access to `httpd.conf`, placing rules here will offer a performance benefit (as the rules are processed once, as opposed to each time the `.htaccess` file is called).

### Logging mod_rewrite requests

Logging may be enabled from within the `httpd.conf` file (including `<Virtual Host>`):

```
# logs can't be enabled from .htaccess
# loglevel > 2 is really spammy!
RewriteLog /path/to/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 2
```

### Common use cases

1. To funnel all requests to a single point:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   # ignore existing files
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
   # ignore existing directories
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
   # map requests to index.php and append as a query string
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1
   ```

   Since Apache 2.2.16 you can also use [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource).
2. Handling 301/302 redirects:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   # 302 Temporary Redirect (302 is the default, but can be specified for clarity)
   RewriteRule ^oldpage\.html$ /newpage.html [R=302]  
   # 301 Permanent Redirect
   RewriteRule ^oldpage2\.html$ /newpage.html [R=301]
   ```

   *Note*: external redirects are implicitly 302 redirects:

   ```
   # this rule:
   RewriteRule ^somepage\.html$ http://google.com
   # is equivalent to:
   RewriteRule ^somepage\.html$ http://google.com [R]
   # and:
   RewriteRule ^somepage\.html$ http://google.com [R=302]
   ```
3. Forcing SSL

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
   ```
4. Common flags:

   - `[R]` or `[redirect]` - force a redirect (defaults to a 302 temporary redirect)
   - `[R=301]` or `[redirect=301]` - force a 301 permanent redirect
   - `[L]` or `[last]` - stop rewriting process (see note below in common pitfalls)
   - `[NC]` or `[nocase]` - specify that matching should be case insensitive

   Using the long-form of flags is often more readable and will help others who come to read your code later.

   You can separate multiple flags with a comma:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^olddir(.*)$ /newdir$1 [L,NC]
   ```

### Common pitfalls

1. Mixing `mod_alias` style redirects with `mod_rewrite`

   ```
   # Bad
   Redirect 302 /somepage.html http://example.com/otherpage.html
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1

   # Good (use mod_rewrite for both)
   RewriteEngine on
   # 302 redirect and stop processing
   RewriteRule ^somepage.html$ /otherpage.html [R=302,L] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   # handle other redirects
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1
   ```

   *Note*: you can mix `mod_alias` with `mod_rewrite`, but it involves more work than just handling basic redirects as above.
2. Context affects syntax

   Within `.htaccess` files, a leading slash is not used in the RewriteRule pattern:

   ```
   # given: GET /directory/file.html

   # .htaccess
   # result: /newdirectory/file.html
   RewriteRule ^directory(.*)$ /newdirectory$1

   # .htaccess
   # result: no match!
   RewriteRule ^/directory(.*)$ /newdirectory$1

   # httpd.conf
   # result: /newdirectory/file.html
   RewriteRule ^/directory(.*)$ /newdirectory$1

   # Putting a "?" after the slash will allow it to work in both contexts:
   RewriteRule ^/?directory(.*)$ /newdirectory$1
   ```
3. [L] is not last! (sometimes)

   The `[L]` flag stops processing any further rewrite rules *for that pass through the rule set*. However, if the URL was modified in that pass and you're in the `.htaccess` context or the `<Directory>` section, then your modified request is going to be passed back through the URL parsing engine again. And on the next pass, it may match a different rule this time. If you don't understand this, it often looks like your `[L]` flag had no effect.

   ```
   # processing does not stop here
   RewriteRule ^dirA$ /dirB [L] 
   # /dirC will be the final result
   RewriteRule ^dirB$ /dirC
   ```

   Our rewrite log shows that the rules are run twice and the URL is updated twice:

   ```
   rewrite 'dirA' -> '/dirB'
   internal redirect with /dirB [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
   rewrite 'dirB' -> '/dirC'
   ```

   The best way around this is to use the `[END]` flag ([see Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end)) instead of the `[L]` flag, if you truly want to stop all further processing of rules (and subsequent passes). However, the `[END]` flag is only available for **Apache v2.3.9+**, so if you have v2.2 or lower, you're stuck with just the `[L]` flag.

   For earlier versions, you must rely on `RewriteCond` statements to prevent matching of rules on subsequent passes of the URL parsing engine.

   ```
   # Only process the following RewriteRule if on the first pass
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
   RewriteRule ...
   ```

   Or you must ensure that your RewriteRule's are in a context (i.e. `httpd.conf`) that will not cause your request to be re-parsed.

Comment: Dude, totally the best article on the internet now on mod rewrite. I hate that thing. Im a lighttpd heretic *because* of how much i hate mod_rewrite.

Comment: This has been THE most useful guide I've found on mod_rewrite so far. Just finding out about RewriteLog helped fix so many problems that what was taking me days to track down turned into a few minutes. (I mean the rules were written but I couldn't figure out why they weren't working)

Comment: 1 year old post, but one of the more useful things I've found on SO - for me.

Comment: If you only have access to `.htaccess` files then you should largely ignore this post as the `.htaccess`-specific advice is often incorrect. e.g. rewrite *substitution* strings should also  *always* omit the leading slash unless you know what you are doing and understand how absolute path redirection works.

Comment: The `[L]` flag means a rule is **last** in current processing, this will not stop rewriting, because they are internal redirects, so your `dirB` apply to `dirC` in next htaccess processing. Alone `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1` will be an infinite loop of internal redirects (in practice it's terminated after 10 iterates). **-1** because you're suggest that _[L] is not last_. It's not terminating rewriting process, but **it's last**.

Comment: I believe `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` is the preferred way to check for an HTTPS connection (in your example of forcing non-ssl traffic to HTTPS)

Comment: Wow, that %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} check is a total lifesaver. You just saved what was left of my hair.

Comment: What does last do. There seem to be no one that can properly explain. Where does it move to after processing L. Does it restart from the beginning. Does it go to the top. s tthe last only if there is a file name in the request. What exactly is going on.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer also covered the case with MultiViews and mod_rewrite. I'm trying to figure out this one right now, and the answer didn't help me, unfortunately.

Comment: It's worth noting that the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives are valid for Apache v2.2.  In 2.4 this has changed now to using LogLevel with some module specific levels, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging.  Also, the [END] flag referenced above is only available for 2.3.9+ versions of apache.

Comment: As @kbec mentioned, the [L] flag ***is*** last, you just have to understand what will trigger the URL parser to resubmit the request for another pass through the rule set.  I've added an answer to this question that covers in more detail how the [L] flag works.

Answer (score 23):

if you need to 'block' internal redirects / rewrites from happening in the .htaccess, take a look at the

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

condition, as [discussed here](http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/ignoring-internal-rewrites-in-htaccess/).

Comment: This is indeed a life saver! People should be more aware of that. In fact, I am going to suggest this to every question about `.*` with `[L]` flag I read before I got here.

Comment: I have seen several modifications to this `200`, `!=200`, `^.`, `^$`.
Apparentely the variable gets set to `200` for a redirect, but also other pages (error and stuff) set it to some value. Now that means that you either check if it `is empty`, `is not empty`, `is 200` or `is not 200`, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 18):

The deal with RewriteBase:

You almost always need to set RewriteBase. If you don't, apache guesses that your base is the physical disk path to your directory. So start with this:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Ah. That totally just fixed the problem I was having. Thanks for that!

Comment: Any way of saying `RewriteBase .`, or something to indicate that it should keep the URL the same, just changing what you've specified?

Comment: Thank you, this is was a priceless piece of info. :)

Comment: You only need to set `RewriteBase` if you are using relative path substitution in the `RewriteRule` directive. It is better to avoid using relative paths.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. In our dev team we avoid `RewriteBase` altogether as nearly all developers misunderstand what it does.  As @w3d said, you only need it if you want to save characters and want to apply the same base to all your RewriteRules in one file.  Your code will likely be clearer to others if you avoid it.

Comment: You *never* need `RewriteBase`, as long as you use absolute substitutions. Read the fine manual at [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

Answer (score 13):

**Other Pitfalls:**

1- Sometimes it's a good idea to disable MultiViews

```
Options -MultiViews
```

I'm not well verse on all of MultiViews capabilities, but I know that it messes up my mod_rewrite rules when active, because one of its properties is to try and 'guess' an extension to a file that it thinks I'm looking for.

I'll explain:
Suppose you have 2 php files in your web dir, file1.php and file2.php and you add these conditions and rule to your .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file1.php/$1
```

You assume that all urls that do not match a file or a directory will be grabbed by file1.php. Surprise! This rule is not being honored for the url http://myhost/file2/somepath. Instead you're taken inside file2.php.

What's going on is that MultiViews automagically guessed that the url that you actually wanted was http://myhost/file2.php/somepath and gladly took you there.

Now, you have no clue what just happened and you're at that point questioning everything that you thought you knew about mod_rewrite. You then start playing around with rules to try to make sense of the logic behind this new situation, but the more you're testing the less sense it makes.

Ok, In short if you want mod_rewrite to work in a way that approximates logic, turning off MultiViews is a step in the right direction.

2- enable FollowSymlinks

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

That one, I don't really know the details of, but I've seen it mentioned many times, so just do it.

Comment: Thanks :) I noticed unexpected surprises like /log/activity turning into /log.txt/activity .. Thanks for the tip :) .. too bad computers never make fun unexpected things happen like accidentally seducing all your female co-workers on facebook :)

Comment: `+FollowSymLinks` is mentioned in the documentation as being mandatory for `mod_rewrite` to work at all, for vague security reasons.

Comment: Two statements here worry me, immensely: 'I'm not well verse on all of MultiViews capabilities, but I know that it messes up my mod_rewrite rules when active' and this one 'That one, I don't really know the details of, but I've seen it mentioned many times, so just do it.' I wish people like you wouldn't write answers on SO about things you are unsure about.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: I think you're mistaking SO for an encyclopedia. It's a community of people coming together to stitch up an understanding of the tech they're working with. Unlike A.W. White and Joey before you, your comment is nearly void of value. MV and FSL are 2 of many Apache's options. My answer is about pitfalls when working with mod_rw specifically, a separate module, which conflicts with some options and works with others. I explained how MV affects mod_rw and mentioned that +FSL is a popular recommendation. Joey confirmed that it's in fact mandatory. What do you bring to the table?

Comment: Thanks.  I just spent the best part of an hour getting a legacy site working and trying to debug the rewrite rules, only to find that MultiViews was overriding it all.

Comment: Just to add to the `FollowSymLinks` note... yes, as Joey states, it is required in order to enable "rewrites in a per-directory context" ([Reference in docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched)). And `Options +FollowSymLinks` (note the `+`) is a safe way to do this, if it isn't already enabled, providing `AllowOverride` is not blocking this in the server config (which is one way to block mod_rewrite in .htaccess files).

Answer (score 5):

**Equation can be done with following example:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(server0|server1).*$ [NC]
# %1 is the string that was found above
# %1<>%{HTTP_COOKIE} concatenates first macht with mod_rewrite variable -> "test0<>foo=bar;"
#RewriteCond search for a (.*) in the second part -> \1 is a reference to (.*)
# <> is used as an string separator/indicator, can be replaced by any other character
RewriteCond %1<>%{HTTP_COOKIE} !^(.*)<>.*stickysession=\1.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://notmatch.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

**Dynamic Load Balancing:**

If you use the mod_proxy to balance your system, it's possible to add a dynamic range of worker server.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*stickysession=route\.server([0-9]{1,2}).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://worker%1.internal.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

A better understanding of the [L] flag is in order. The [L] flag **is** last, you just have to understand what will cause your request to be routed through the URL parsing engine again.  From the docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) (emphasis mine):

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or
>   the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.
>
> ***If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in `<Directory>` sections***, it is important to have some understanding of
>   how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once
>   the rules have been processed, ***the rewritten request is handed back*** to
>   the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that
>   as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or `<Directory>`
>   section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run
>   again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the
>   rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the
>   request process to start over.

So the [L] flag ***does*** stop processing any further rewrite rules for ***that pass*** through the rule set.  However, if your rule marked with [L] modified the request, and you're in the .htaccess context or the `<Directory>` section, then your modifed request is going to be passed back through the URL parsing engine again.  And on the next pass, it may match a different rule this time.  If you don't understand what happened, it looks like your first rewrite rule with the [L] flag had no effect.

The best way around this is to use the [END] flag (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) instead of the [L] flag, if you truly want to stop all further processing of rules (and subsequent reparsing).  However, the [END] flag is only available for Apache v2.3.9+, so if you have v2.2 or lower, you're stuck with just the [L] flag.  In this case, you must rely on RewriteCond statements to prevent matching of rules on subsequent passes of the URL parsing engine.  Or you must ensure that your RewriteRule's are in a context (i.e. httpd.conf) that will not cause your request to be re-parsed.

Answer (score 3):

Another great feature are rewrite-map-expansions. They're especially useful if you have a massive amout of hosts / rewrites to handle:

They are like a key-value-replacement:

```
RewriteMap examplemap txt:/path/to/file/map.txt
```

Then you can use a mapping in your rules like:

```
RewriteRule ^/ex/(.*) ${examplemap:$1}
```

More information on this topic can be found here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#mapfunc

Comment: Ignore this feature if you are using `.htaccess`-based rewrites.  It doesn't work in this context.

Comment: The RewriteMap directive must be used in server context (httpd.conf), but once defined there, you may use the map via the RewriteRule in an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite can modify aspects of request handling without altering the URL, e.g. setting environment variables, setting cookies, etc. This is incredibly useful.

Conditionally set an environment variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} myCookie=(a|b) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MY_ENV_VAR:%b]
```

Return a 503 response:
`RewriteRule`'s `[R]` flag can take a non-3xx value and return a non-redirecting response, e.g. for managed downtime/maintenance:

```
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

will return a 503 response (not a *redirect* per se).

Also, mod_rewrite can act like a super-powered interface to mod_proxy, so you can do this instead of writing `ProxyPass` directives:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://cluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

Opinion:
Using `RewriteRule`s and `RewriteCond`s to route requests to different applications or load balancers based on virtually any conceivable aspect of the request is just immensely powerful. Controlling requests on their way to the backend, and being able to modify the responses on their way back out, makes mod_rewrite the ideal place to centralize all routing-related config.

Take the time to learn it, it's well worth it! :)