# Mod-rewrite shenanigans

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /location/
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?franchise=$1
```

Which is suppose to change this URL

```
http://example.com/location/kings-lynn
```

Into this one

```
http://example.com/location/index.php?franchise=kings-lynn
```

But instead I am getting this

```
http://example.com/location/index.php?franchise=index.php
```

Also, adding a railing slash breaks it. I get index.php page showing but none of the style sheets or javascript are loading.

I'm clearly doing something very wrong but I have no idea what despite spending all day R'ingTFM and many online primers and tutorials and questions on here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-modrewrite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is you are redirecting twice.

`'location/index.php'` matches the regex `^(.+)/?$`

You want to possibly use the "if file does not exist" conditional to make it not try mapping a second time.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /location/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   # ignore existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   # ignore existing directories
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?franchise=$1  [L,QSA]
```

And additonally, theres the [L,QSA] which tries to make it the "last" rule ( Note, this is not entirely obvious how it works ) and append the query string to the query, so that

```
location/foobar/?baz=quux  ==> index.php?franchise=$1&baz=quux
```

( i think )

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me as though the rewrite filter is executing twice.  Try adding a last flag

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?franchise=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your rule self matches, and therefore it will reference itself.