# How to apply 301 redirection from aspx website to wordpress?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, redirect

I have old site in asp.net and i want to redirect the pages into new wordpress site, 
Old domain : http://manakjewels.com/TradeShow.aspx
New One : manakjewels/tradeshow.htm

How to do this, please explain me step by step.
That will be really helpful.

Comment: Have you looked around for an answer? There are many existing resources around this topic in the internet.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355318/301-redirect

Comment: What is the server environment?

Comment: yes but i got confused, should i just paste the 301 redirection code to .htaccess file ? will that work ?