# Unable to make a 301 redirection from siteA.com/* to siteB.com/*

Tags: .htaccess

I just moved my site from siteA.com to siteB.com.
There are hundreds of articles published in siteA.com.

Google finds still only articles on siteA.com.

**Example of the problem**

I can find the following articles in Google

```
www.siteA.com/article1
...
www.siteA.com/article777
```

I need to make make 301 domain redirection from each article at siteA to siteB's articles such that

```
www.siteB.com/article1
...
www.siteB.com/article777
```

This would require 777 domain redirections in .htaccess.

**Is there any easier way to make the domain redirections** than writing 1555 lines of code in .htaccess -file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-modrewrite  might also be of use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why 777 domain redirections? Just put:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.siteB.com/
```

into the .htaccess file in the document root of `www.siteA.com`.