# htaccess/mod_rewrite doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?var=10&view=3$

RewriteRule ^/index.php$ http://www.domain.com/index.php?var=11&view=1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=10&view=3$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.domain.com/index.php?var=11&view=1
```

See [common pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/) (item #2), in the .htaccess file, the leading "/" is not necessary. Also, the leading "?" in the RewriteCond is unnecessary.