# How can I make the -f flag apply to directories with a trailing slash?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am building a `.htaccess` file with a fairly complex ruleset.

One of the basic rewriting rules is this first line:

**If a requested file exists physically, no rewriting, stop processing rules.**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

this works well with one exception: When I access a directory with a **trailing slash**

```
www.example.com/directory/
```

`directory` will not be recognized as existant, whereas

```
www.example.com/directory
```

will.

**What can I do to make Apache recognize existing directories with a trailing slash as well?**

Background info, I am already *adding* trailing slash to every request made without one (to cater for both `/directory` and `/directory/` requests.

Comment: To be precise: `/foobar/` does not refer to the directory named *foobar* but to the index document in the directory *foobar*. Apache is doing a subrequest if `/foobar/` is requested. Only `/foobar` does refer to the directory named *foobar*.

Comment: @Gumbo good point. So I'll probably have no choice but to shave off the trailing slash in internal processing. Will try that.

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite’s logging feature (see `RewriteLogLevel`) to see how your requests are processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

The -d stands for directory. Also, according to [Hidden features of mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite) , the [L] directive doesn't work in .htacess files, just if you put it in your apache conf files.

Also if you simply start off with:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Dont rewrite files or directories which actually exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

You can avoid rewriting any existing files or directories. Your existing rules says "If this is a real file, keep going" whereas mine says "If its not a real file and its not a real directory, keep going."

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot. [L] not working in .htaccess explains a lot too. I'm off for now, will test this tomorrow.

Comment: Can you post your entire .htaccess? The second group of lines I posted starting with `RewriteEngine on` is exactly what i use to redirect any file or directory which does not exist to a specific file (with the unshown rewrite rule).