# How to simulate [L] in .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file with a number of RewriteRules.

How can I exclude already existing files and directories from having run through each of the `RewriteCond` / `RewriteRule` pairs?

This:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .*  - [F,L]
```

won't work reliably because according to [**this SO question:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite)

> within the .htaccess context, [L] will not force mod_rewrite  to stop. it will continue to trigger internal sub-requests:

How can I make this work?
Alternatively, is ther a control structure like **if condition applies, go through this block of rules, otherwise skip and go to end** in mod_rewrite?

Comment: Should be posted on ServerFault

Comment: Yeah, I had that discussion already with my last mod_rewrite question. Well, if five people feel that way then migrate it if you must, but as long as we're answering *all sorts* of HTML questions here on SO that have *much, much less* to do with programming than any mod_rewrite question, I will continue posting mod_rewrite questions here. (not attacking you in any way here @Steen. This just needed to get out at the right occasion, which happened to be this question.)

Comment: Cheers. Glad to give the opportunity :) What's important is that you get your question answered, which it seems you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your rule is that both conditions can not be fulfilled at the same time because a regular file (`-f`) cannot also be a directory (`-d`). Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: (slaps head) of course. Thanks Gumbo. Can I rely on `[L]` working in this context despite what the quote says?

Comment: Should be ok, you can always add the [NS] flag to the rule (ie. [L,NS]) which means ignore for internal sub-requests.  Best way is to suck it and see unfortunately, mod_rewrite is a bit of a black art :)

Comment: Strange. Does anybody know why `-d` does *not* apply to resources requested with a trailing slash `www.example.com/directory/`?

Comment: @Pekka: The *L* flag does only cause an internal redirect if the URI is changed. So your rule won’t cause an internal redirect.

Comment: I have a related issue in case anybody's interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218971/how-can-i-make-the-f-flag-apply-to-directories-with-a-trailing-slash