# How come the [L] flag isn't working in my .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here are the rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ index.php?action=home [L]
RewriteRule ^[\w\W]*$ error.php [L]
```

When a page matches the first one, it is supposed to ignore any other further rules. Yet accessing `/` results in `error.php` being invoked. Commenting out the second rule works as intended - the page redirects to `index.php`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Also:** is there a better way to write the last line? It's basically a catch-all.

Comment: I need the last rule to take effect **only if the other rules did not match**.

Comment: Maybe cause `within the .htaccess context, [L] will not force mod_rewrite to stop` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite/286005#286005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change

`^[\w\W]*$` to `^[\w\W]+$` or `^.+$`

Comment: But then `/a`, `/b`, `/c`, etc. would not match.

Comment: No, they would. `+` is "one or more", while `*` is zero or more.

Answer (score 0):

If the last line is a catch-all, just do `RewriteRule ^.*$ error.php [L]`

Your first line might be erroring out when you send a request for `/` because your rule is saying "nothing" and you are sending `/`.

Try changing your rule to `RewriteRule ^/$ index.php?action=home [L]`