# mod_rewrite: allow redirect but prevent direct access

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently using mod_rewrite to do an internal redirection

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/pattern$
RewriteRUle .* file.php
```

However I would like to prevent direct access to `file.php` by redirecting requests to that file to a page not found URL.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /file.php
RewriteRule .* page-not-found.php
```

The problem is that the second rule also applies when I do the first redirect and therefore breaks my first internal redirect.

**[Q] Is there a way to allow the first redirect but prevent direct access to the redirected file?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** Inspired by @AndrewR's answer (which in its current form however didn't seem to work for me - it looks like the second rule gets applied anyway.) a .htaccess only solution that works with a secret key.

If you encounter a valid pattern, add a secret key to the query string.

Then test for that secret key when deciding upon the page redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/pattern$
RewriteRule .* /file.php?SUPER_SEKRIT_KEY [QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !SUPER_SEKRIT_KEY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /file.php
RewriteRule .* /test/page-not-found.php [L,F]
```

Use a more complex key of course, and  for internal redirects only! Otherwise, the user will be able to grab the secret key.

Comment: instead of  secret key an environment variable with the E tag would maybe be less intrusive (not altering the QUERY_STRING which may be used later)

Comment: @regilero can you give a short example please?

Comment: I think @regilero means something like "RewriteRule .* - [E=key:SEKRITVALUE]" followed by a RewriteCond test on %{ENV:key}. However, I can't get that to work...

Answer (score 10):

Using `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` variable (see [mromaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228162/mromaine)'s [contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2688558/1048171) to ["Hidden features of mod_rewrite" community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite):

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/pattern$
RewriteRule .* file.php

# Redirect direct access to file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /file.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule .* page-not-found.php
```

Test cases:

- http://example.com request gets server's index file (index.htm, index.php, etc.)
- http://example.com/somefile.htm request gets `somefile.htm`
- http://example.com/somedir request gets `somedir`'s index file
- http://example.com/pattern request gets `file.php` file
- http://example.com/file.php request gets `page-not-found.php` file

Every HTTP responses are HTTP 200.

Comment: +1 for `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /file.php` with `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` this solves one for me. thanks!

Comment: Are environments stored per client session? I mean is it safe to use them like above while multiple requests might arrive concurrently?

Comment: I think environment variables are per-request, especially this one (`ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS`) which is filled by internal Apache process.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [L] at the end of the rewrite rule, which signifies Last, or no more processing. This will only work inside the Apache config. It does not work in an .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  pattern$
RewriteRule .* /file.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} file.php$
RewriteRule .* /page-not-found.php [L]
```

Comment: This won't block access to `file.php` though?

Comment: I only included the one rewrite rule as an example. I added the second for clarity. They are both required.

Comment: Mm, I can't get this to work on my Apache 2. Are you sure this can work?

Comment: Can't get that to work either, that's the first thing I tried.

Comment: I thought it would be fine in an .htaccess, but I guess not. If you put it inside your httpd.conf (or virtualhosts) it does work. Something to do with the way .htaccess is processed. I have updated my answer one more time with what I have used inside my Apache config and have had it working. I am going to post another answer that might be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to do this only using .htaccess.

Move your file.php into a new directory called securedir. In the root directory use this .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pattern$ securedir/file.php
```

Prevent access to anything in securedir with this in an .htaccess file there. (Or direct them back to a different page if you prefer.)

```
deny from all
```

Comment: Thanks. what lines do you but before `deny from all` for .htaccess to understand it's related to the securedir directory?

Comment: Nothing else. It goes into it's own .htaccess file inside of securedir.