# Please assist in mod rewriting application/views directory to "views" in Kohana

Tags: .htaccess, kohana-3

Due to the way I have chosen to template my website, I am needing to rewrite "application/views" to "views". I have chosen to do this (1) to shorten the URL I'll be using in linking stylesheets etc as well as covering up the structure of my file system.

Currently, if I remove the rewrite rule I can access the media files directly at application/views/template/file.css. When I enable the rewrite rule I am redirected to views/template/file.css but Kohana returns: **Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: template/u_crossbrowser/css/bootstrap.css**

I imagine I could dig into the script and make a condition stating that if url is calling views dir, do not try to control the routing. But I imagine there is a better solution.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>


#We needed direct file access for our media files (css, js, images) but the rewrite below was breaking it. So, we replaced it with rule 2 below.
    # Protect application and system files from being viewed
    # RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b - [F,L]

# Rule 2: Disable directory listings
IndexIgnore *

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /application/views/
RewriteRule ^application/views/(.*) /views/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1. Your rule to rewrite `/application/views/...` to `/views/...` is *after* the rule that rewrites **everything** to `index.php`.  You need to put the more-specific rewrite *before* the more-general rewrite to prevent the more-general one from stopping the processing.
2. Your rewrite rule is incomplete.  You have a rule so that requests to `/application/views/...` get rewritten as if the files are actually at `/views/...`.  However, *since you are still actually storing the files in the `application/views/` folder*, you are missing the rule that lets you access them *as if they are at `/views/...`*.

Here is one way you could make the rewrite rules in order to get it to work. (I left out the rule that redirects `/application/views/...` to `/views/...` because I don't see why you need it - just make `/application` inaccessible and only use `/views/...` and then it won't matter anyway.)

```
RewriteEngine on

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Pretend that views are one directory above where they actually are
RewriteRule ^views/(.*) application/views/$1 [L]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed,
# UNLESS we are redirecting to them from another rule
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b - [F,L]


# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT]
```

(thanks to @CDuv's answer to [mod_rewrite: allow redirect but prevent direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769459/mod-rewrite-allow-redirect-but-prevent-direct-access) for the `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` trick.)

---

In truth, you may find that it makes more sense to create a route to this content.  This is because it allows you to move the `application`, `modules`, and `system` directories out of the web root.  One benefit of doing this is that you can share the `modules` and `system` between multiple Kohana applications if  you ever develop another one.  Another is that it means you don't need to rely on htaccess to protect access to these directories.

Here is a simple method you can use to serve these files, based on the [Kohana Userguide](https://github.com/kohana/userguide) module.

Add this route in `bootstrap.php`:

```
// Static file serving (CSS, JS, images) - ADD MORE EXTENSIONS IF NEEDED
Route::set('media', 'views(/<file>)', array('file' => '.+\.(css|js|jpg|png)'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'media',
        'action'     => 'media',
        'file'       => NULL,
    ));
```

Add a controller `Controller_Media`:

```
class Controller_Media extends Controller
{
    public function action_media()
    {
        // Get the file path from the request
        $file = $this->request->param('file');

        // Find the file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // Remove the extension from the filename
        $file = substr($file, 0, -(strlen($ext) + 1));

        if ($file = Kohana::find_file('views', $file, $ext))
        {
            // Check if the browser sent an "if-none-match: <etag>" header, and tell if the file hasn't changed
            $this->check_cache(sha1($this->request->uri()).filemtime($file));

            // Send the file content as the response
            $this->response->body(file_get_contents($file));

            // Set the proper headers to allow caching
            $this->response->headers('content-type',  File::mime_by_ext($ext));
            $this->response->headers('last-modified', date('r', filemtime($file)));
        }
        else
        {
            // Return a 404 status
            $this->response->status(404);
        }
    }
}
```