# .htaccess file 404 error with parallel plesk server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, plesk

I have my .htaccess file working in localhost. But its not working if i upload it in server. It throws me 404 error.

I am using Parallel Plesk 11.0.9 and i can't find `conf` file for the same on that. If anyone has any idea how to fix it or any workaround for url rewriting would be great help.

Anyway here's the code in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^store/living/Hutches-Armoires-Side-tables-Coffee-tables-Entertainment-centers? store.php?store=Living
RewriteRule ^store/dining/sideboards-buffets-chairs-benches-Dining-table$ store.php?store=Dining
RewriteRule ^store/working/Bookshelves-Study-tables$ store.php?store=Working
RewriteRule ^store/accessories/Boxes-Photo-Frames-Mirror-Frames-Block-Stamps-and-Book-stands$ store.php?store=Accessories
RewriteRule ^store/hallway/Console-tables-Armoires$ store.php?store=Hallway
RewriteRule ^store/sleeping/Bed-Frames-Night-Stands-Dressers-Mirror-framesBed-Linens-Canopies-Curtains$ store.php?store=Sleeping
```

Comment: can you post the full url that is generating the 404? also, can you post the file that the 404 is reporting missing(as these two may not be the same)?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap your rewrite rules with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
...
</IfModule>
```

...probably a good idea anyway.

Or you could try putting your rules into a vhost.conf file in the conf directory immediately below the location of your httpdocs directory.  For example on a Centos machine the web root might be

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs
```

and you should have a:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf
```

directory, this will contain a set of pregenerated Apache config files that Plesk creates.  If there isn't already create a vhost.conf and add your rules between a set of

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ >

... your rules ...

</Directory>
```

Once you've created the vhost.conf file you will need to tell plesk about it with

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain domain.com
```

If you still can't get it to work you can add a log for mod_rewrite, see this [relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite) for details

Answer (score 0):

Is your Plesk running IIS and supporting PHP via FastCGI or ISAPI? If that is the case, check whether [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is installed and follow [this guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) to translate htaccess (for apache) into web.config (for IIS)