# Force a specific Zend Framework controller via URL rewriting

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite

In a Zend Framework (v1.12) application I want to force a specific controller (`api`) to be called.

I've managed to rewrite any request so that whatever the request is (*eg.* "http://example.com/foo/bar" or "http://example.com"), it's rewritten to http://example.com/api/... (*eg.* "http://example.com/api/foo/bar" or "http://example.com/api/") with the following Apache rewrite rules:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    [...]
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?api/?.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /api/$1 [R,L]
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

RewriteLogs says:

```
/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /api/
/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/?(.*)$' to uri '/api/'
/initial] (1) pass through /api/
/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.com/public/api -> /var/www/example.com/public/api/
/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.com/public/api/ -> api/
/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'api/'
/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.com/public/api -> /var/www/example.com/public/api/
/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.com/public/api/ -> api/
/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'api/'
/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] rewrite 'api/' -> 'index.php'
/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/example.com/public/index.php
/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/example.com/public/index.php -> /index.php
/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/example.com/public/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.php
/initial/redir#1] (3) applying pattern '^/?(.*)$' to uri '/index.php'
/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /index.php
```

But this still allow users to access application's home page via http://example.com/index.php and I can't manage to forbid this.

I tried to block:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    [...]
    # Rewrite code from above
    [...]
    <Location /index.php>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </Location>
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

But being a ZF application, every request has to pass to index.php (the Bootstrap): the standard ZF rewrite rules rewrites everything to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Thus I get a "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server." for every request.

Can I allow access to "index.php" when used for rewritten request and forbid direct access to it?

I'm sure this could be done by the ZF application's router but would like to avoid changing the application's PHP source code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` variable (see [mromaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228162/mromaine)'s [contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2688558/1048171) to ["Hidden features of mod_rewrite" community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite) I've managed to forbid direct access to `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force controller "api"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?api/?.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /api/$1 [R,L]

# Deny direct access to "index.php"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule index\.php$ - [NC,F]
```

Test cases:

- http://example.com/index.php gets a 403 Forbidden
- http://example.com gets a 302 to http://example.com/api/
- http://example.com/foo gets a 302 to http://example.com/api/foo
- http://example.com/api gets a 200 to http://example.com/api