# How to redirect link?

Tags: redirect, web

I need redirect website A to website B but only main domain, keep the rest.

For example:

> http://google.com/hello redirect to: http://bing.com/hello

Only change google.com to bing.com

This is code I am using but it redirect all.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://bing.com/hello".$_GET["tid"]);
?>
```

I have many keywords, so I can't redirect manually.
Please help me ! Thank you ! Sorry for my poor English !

Comment: Do you have control over your server? Google "rewrite engine".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite - come back if you still have questions after that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the `.htaccess` file at the *root* of your old domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will direct everything from your `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com`. The `$1` ensures that "everything after the root" is preserved exactly as it was before. The response code `301` means "permanent redirect" - it tells the browser making the request "we have moved". The `L` means "this is the last statement in the processing" - so no further rules get processed for something that matched the `RewriteCond`itions.

You have to make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled. This usually involves checking the `httpd.conf` file, making sure the correct line is uncommented, and restarting your server.

More info at http://www.orderofbusiness.net/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/ or https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en - or any of thousands of other sites...