# PHP URL Controller Route

Tags: php, .htaccess, controller, routes

So I have a php file called lets say "foo.php". 
I want foo.php to act as a controller (like in a MVC Framework except I am using regular PHP). So lets say when a user goes to url.com/foo.php/1, I want it to do the same thing as foo.php?id=1

Would I handle something like this in the .htaccess or is it possible to do it just via the foo.php file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hidden features of mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Yes, assuming your using Apache webserver you would need to use `mod_rewrite` and a `.htaccess` file for this

Comment: This sounds like a simple mod-rewrite in htacces. I suggest following some tutorial at the internet which give you some basics on MVC an clean URL like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbBf4jfwWko)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned MVC, it sounds like what you're really after is a [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Here is a nice tutorial to get you started: [Front Controller Pattern](http://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/).

Basically it's a combination of PHP and `.htaccess`. The `.htaccess` file routes ALL requests to `foo.php`, which then translates the url parameters as follows:

```
example.com/controller/method/param1/param2/etc...
```