# Advanced htaccess Redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, web

Using mod_rewrite, I have a series of server-side redirects (Meaning that the client is not made aware of the URI changes.)  I want to make it so that any client-side references to index.php return a 404 error without disruption to the server-sided requests...

--

Example..

Client requests x.html, it loads the content of index.php..

Client requests index.php, client gets a 404 Not Found error..

--

I understand that this is poorly formed and could probably be explained a lot better but I'm hoping that this is explained well enough - if it's not, I apologize...

--

I've spent the last three hours on google, trying to find the solution to this and have come up short as I don't really know what it would be understood as...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your context : if you are **NOT** in a `.htaccess` or in a `<Directory>`, this is easy :

```apache2
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  /index.php     -           [L,R=404]
RewriteRule  /x.html        /index.php  [L]
```

If you **are** in a `.htaccess` or in a `<Directory>`, the request is processed a second time, see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l).
I used an environment variable to work around that :

```apache2
RewriteEngine On
# after an internal redirect, the variable is prefixed with REDIRECT_
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_redirect_to_php} !=true
# no leading / this time
RewriteRule  index.php     -           [L,R=404]
RewriteRule  x.html        /index.php  [L,E=redirect_to_php:true]
```

You can use [RewriteLog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and [RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) to get the details of the rewrite execution.

Comment: Thanks so much!
Edit:
I'm in the root of the website and not using any directory tags or anything of the such but the first option is still returning a 404 trying to load index.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [END] tag is what you are searching. As David mentioned, the problem is that the request is processed a second time. As far as I unterstand, you can use [END] to prevent this behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/286005/4751174 (at the end of the answer) or the mod_rewrite doc:

> Using the [END] flag terminates not only the current round of rewrite processing (like [L]) but also prevents any subsequent rewrite processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context.
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end

Needs Apache 2.3.9 or later.

Comment: I already verified and accepted the previous answer.  It is fully functional in the way that I want it to be.