# Rewrite URLs containing subdirectories to script in root

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect pages in a way that the language indicator, which in the URL is expressed as a subfolder ("en/", "de/" ...), is converted to a parameter I can work with. "FR", as the site's main language, does not have a language subfolder.

To illustrate this:

```
www.domain/index.html
```

should redirect to

```
www.domain/index.php?lang=fr
```

and

```
www.domain/en/index.html
```

should redirect to

```
www.domain/index.php?lang=en
```

I've tried the following in my .htaccess file (which is located in the root directory):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/index\.html$ /index.php?lang=en [L]   
RewriteRule ^de/index\.html$ /index.php?lang=de [L] 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php?lang=fr [L]
```

The last one works as expected, however the first two return a 404. For the second line ("de version"), I get:

```
The requested URL /de/index.php was not found on this server.
```

Apache logs the following:

```
[Thu Jul 09 13:14:28 2015] [error] [client ::1] script '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testsite/de/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

It would appear that the first two rules are completely ignored by the server, as changing the target file name in the second line as below:

```
RewriteRule ^de/index\.html$ /blah.php?lang=de [L]
```

still triggers the same 404 message stating the missing de/index.php and not blah.php ;

What does work however is placing a .htaccess in a subfolder named 'de' and pointing from there to the index.php in the root folder with

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php?lang=de [L]
```

But that's not a proper solution, is it ?

Comment: Are these really all the rules? Which path does the `error.log` document? Enable rewrite logging.

Comment: i see the only problem - add leading slash in the 2nd rule `RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php?lang=fr [L]`

Comment: */en/index.php* - who has changed extension from `html`?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(en)/(index\.html)$ index.php?lang=en [L]

Comment: @Eric ok. and who return ^/en/ ? I think that there are more lines in htaccess

Comment: @splash58 Could you please explain what the use of changing the second rule, which works correctly, would be?

Comment: @Argoron  i don't understand what is  happened with input url that /en/index.HTML became /en/index.PHP No rule, making so,  in this code

Comment: Do you have any other rules there?

Comment: @Starkeen Not yet because I've only just started rebuilding the whole thing.

Comment: Clear your browser's cache, may be it's  because of that.

Comment: @mario Done. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Maybe one of those rare cases where `RewriteBase /` may help. Due to potential overlap even `Options -MultiViews`. And the target rule typically goes better without `/` prefix in `/index…?…`

Comment: @mario I tried RewriteBase early in my attempts to make this work but to no avail. Also just tried Options -MultiViews and removed the leading slashes. Oddly, these "en" and "de" rules still do not get applied, the default one (no subdirectory) though does. If I change the target file name to blah.php for the default rule, I get an appropriate error message ( blah.php not found), whereas for the other two it's /xx/index.php not found ...

Comment: At this point you should really enable and inspect the RewriteLog. At the least also prevent multiple rounds using `[END]` instead of `[L]`, because this still reads like interacting rules. Existing `en/` or `de/` subdirs should be absent for further tests.

Comment: See also [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108) (sorry for the length),  [Hidden features of mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/286004), and lastly [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/q/214512) for additional tips

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, adding this line before the rules helps:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Also, in some server configurations, you need to start with `^/` instead of just `^`. So a rule would look like this:
    RewriteRule ^/en/index.html /index.php?lang=en

This solved it once for me.

Just a tip:

Both EN and DE rules can be written as a single rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/index.html /index.php?lang=$1
```

This can also be expanded to as many locales as you want, just separate them with a `|` symbol. `|` is basically an `OR` operator.

---

I've tested these and they seem to do what you need:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html /index.php?lang=fr [L]
```

`/index.html` -> `/index.php?lang=fr`

---

```
RewriteRule ^en/index\.html /index.php?lang=en [L]
```

`/en/index.html` -> `/index.php?lang=en`

---

```
RewriteRule ^de/index\.html /index.php?lang=de [L]
```

`/de/index.html` -> `/index.php?lang=de`

---

Another, less limited solution would look something along these lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/index.html /index.php?lang=$1
```

`/xx/index.html` -> `/index.php?lang=xx`

This actually takes any two characters and sets them where the $1 is. But this might not be what you really want, it's just a tip.

---

P.S. This is a nice tool for testing rewrite rules: [LINK](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)