# How to run PHP and Perl program in one server(Apache)

Tags: php, apache, perl

I want to put my PHP program on Apache server(there are existing Perl program running there).
And I want to invoke those programs independently.

For example)

"http://my-address/existing-program" goes to Perl program,

on the other hand, "http://my-address/new-program" goes to PHP program.

I might need to modify "httpd.conf" but I am not sure how.
Any advise would be helpful.

Kind regards.

Comment: Doesn't apache deal with `.pl` as knowing to parse in PeRL and `.php` knows to parse in PHP?

Comment: take a look to apache virtual hosts. It is not a problem of running different programming languages applications. Have a look at this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: sissy, Thank you so much I will read the link!

Answer (score 1):

You could use mod_rewrite calls in your httpd.conf file to intercept specific URLs and make sure they're routed and handled accordingly.

[Hidden features of mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite)